# Template creation tool for contracts

Tags: intranet

A question for my mothers real estate office. She has a number of contracts and documents that she gives to her agents.  Frequently the agents have trouble figuring out the forms, or often overwriting them (instead of copying the file first).

She would like a tool that allows her to take contracts and populate them from a simple fill in form.

Does such a thing exist?

Comment: Can you help us a little and give us more information about what format these contracts or documents are in? Word? Just plain-text? Something else?

Comment: the document can be any format. Google docs, libre office, or ms office.  I'd actually prefer an online solution.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - Create the document that you want, then go to save as and scroll down the list of `Save as Type` to `Document Template (.dot)` (or possibly .dotx), then copy this file to everyones computer in the `%appdata%\microsoft\templates` folder.

The %appdata% shortcut should take you straight to the correct place - if you can't find it, try c:\users\your_name_here\appdata\roaming\microsoft\templates